# call externalinterface js in a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript, externalinterface

I wants to make interface with Flash video. 
How could i import/embed externalinterface js in a HTML page. to make call to control flash video. 
How to add Action script on HTML page.
With these i wants to make some interface in between flash and external interface js.

my previous question

I have around 100 pages and all have their only one flash video. I wants to make a script when the currently playing video end then will show the next page link to go on next flash video and resume/rewind. I have no idea how to do it.. i think it is possible with java script or with action script.

Any help please.

Any example

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a "watcher" on this on flash fisrt:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionScript", receivedFromJavaScript);
```

after this, the .swf will be ready to receive information from javascript. You can do this using on javascript:

```
window["NameOfYourSwf"].sendToActionScript(value);
```

you also can avoid some Microsoft errors using `thisMovie("NameOfYourSwf")`:

```
function thisMovie(movieName) {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
     } else {
         return document[movieName];
     }
 }
```

more information:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

best...